# Confusion with Joda Time DateTime#centuryOfEra()

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I was using the below method from JodaTime library [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class and expected it to return value 21.

```
DateTime#centuryOfEra()
```

It returns value 20 which makes me confused. Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this official [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/field.html), the minimum value of the field **centuryOfEra** is 1, but when joda-time use [ISOChronology](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology.html) then the minimum value is 0.

By default, joda-time use ISOChronology, so the **centuryOfEra** field is "zero based".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which chronology you use.

With the [Gregorian/Julian chronology](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/GJChronology.html), you would indeed get the 21st century.

But [ISOChronology](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/ISOChronology.html) starts at 0.

> With the exception of century related fields, ISOChronology is exactly the same as GregorianChronology. **In this chronology, centuries and year of century are zero based**. For all years, the century is determined by dropping the last two digits of the year, ignoring sign. The year of century is the value of the last two year digits.